# How to auto refresh the page only one time?

Tags: page-refresh

I've a web page when a user logs in, it will have a link that shows the "username" and a link for "logout".

After the user logs out, the "username" and the "logout" links will change to "login" and "register" links, respectively.

The page uses javascript to check a user cookie, if the user cookie exists, it will show the "username" link and the link for "logout". If no user cookie exists, "login" and "register" links will replace the "username" and "logout" links.

Here's the problem: When a user who has log in, clicks the "logout" link, a perl script will delete the user cookie, and redirects back to the same page. The page does not show "login" and "register" links AUTOMATICALLY. Both links will appear ONLY after the user MANUALLY Refreshes the page.

It appears that I need a system to refresh the page automacally ONLY one time. How can this be done?

Comment: would you like a JavaScript only solution? perhaps if you elaborate on what server side technology you are using we can give a more appropriate solution. However, a correct solution would not lie within forcing a refresh, but getting the data right the first go.

Comment: Don't understand your comment at all. Server side technology is very simple, a perl script deletes the user cookie, then redirects back to the same page. However, the changes in the links will appear only after manually refreshing the page. I need that happens automatically.

Comment: The cookie is deleted by setting cookie expired time to ''. Will this cause the problem?

Comment: i meant that instead of refreshing the page, try and see why the perl redirection isn't getting the screen to behave the way you want it immediately.

Comment: Perl logout does its job correctly. It deletes the cookie, redirects back to the original page. But the page does not make the changes until I refresh it. This confuses users because they have logged out, return to the same page, still see their username and logout link there. I can make it works and not confusing to the users, by redirecting them to an intermediate page with a link back to the original page. When they click on the link and return to the original page, they see the changes. But I want to eliminate this intermediate page, and I cannot make it work.

Comment: _But the page does not make the changes until I refresh it._

why is that? can it not redirect and send the new page?

Comment: If I know the answer you are asking, I will not be here now.

Comment: Changes in the page are done by Javascript. I'm not a Javascript expert. When it re-directs to the original page, it would appear the Javascript is not called and it explained why the page is not changed. When the page is refreshed (or manually clicked in the case of the intermediate page), the Javascript is called, checked and found user cookie is not there, then made the changes. Maybe you tell me how to call the Javacript when it is redirected back to the same page?

Comment: perhaps the original JavaScript event is not registered in the correct location, meaning that it's not i.e. body onload event where by it would be called in both cases. you could either change the registration of the javascript or manually call the function with the perl after redirect. as these comments are getting too long, ask a new question relating to your javascript and give us the issue.

Comment: Are you doing the logout using javascript or by submitting an html form? If it is via javascript then it can be changed on page. If it is using a form then it is best done on the server. Note I'm not saying anything is broken, but for a different result something must be changed.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this
after deconnexion redirect to 'page.html?1'
and in javascript side use this snippet
to check for the ?1 and redirect to 'page.html'

```
var refreshCheck= Number(window.location.search.slice(1));
if (refreshCheck == 1 ) {
    window.location.href = window.location.substring(0, window.location.length-2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont think it's good to force a refresh for this kind of things and you should consider the way you are dealing with the operation but if you want the easy way then you have to add this code which will refresh immediately

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">
```

Comment: No, your suggestion does not work. The page will keep on refreshing, very annoying!